# MVC3 EditorFor and generic types throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics, editorfor

I have a Generic type SelectableViewModel

```
public class SelectableViewModel<T> where T : class
{
    public SelectableViewModel(T model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public T Model { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

It wraps a ViewModel so that the user can select or deselect the model from the view.

Controller method

```
public ActionResult ListReconsiledAssignments()
{
    return View(
        assignmentRepository.ListReconsiled()
            .Select(a => new SelectableViewModel<Assignment>(a))
        );
}
```

The view

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectableViewModel<Assignment>>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Request snapshot";
}

<h2>Request snapshot</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m, "SelectableAssignment")
</table>
```

The editor for template named SelectableAssignment.cshtml

```
@model SelectableViewModel<Assignment>

<tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)</td>
    <td>@Model.Model.KufId</td>
    <td>@Model.Model.Name</td>
</tr>
```

This throws exception

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Domain.Assignment,Web.Models.SelectableViewModel`1[Domain.Assignment]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Web.Models.SelectableViewModel`1[Domain.Assignment]'.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the editor template requires single `SelectableViewModel<Assignment>`, but you pass `IEnumerable<SelectableViewModel<Assignment>>` and explicitely instruct it to use `"SelectableAssignment"` template, so exception is thrown. You could iterate over your model and call editor template one by one like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(m => item, "SelectableAssignment")
}
```

Or, simply, remove that template name from `EditorFor` method call from your code. Framework should figure out that it should call `EditorFor` for every item in passed collection

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

Or, the same, call

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Comment: It can not figure it out since its a generic type, tried doing it in a loop like your example, but the model binder could not figure out how to deserialize the posted data to the model (I got a IEnum = null)...

Comment: Let me clearify, @Html.EditorFor(m => m) can not be used because it cant figure out which Editor to bind against since its a generic type. If i define the name It will try to bind a list to a single model view.. So what I need is a way to do the same thing as @Html.EditorFor(m => m) but to a spefific view